# style attribute ignored on deployed page

Tags: html, internet-explorer

The following markup (cleaned up to keep it brief) is generated the same in my VS2010 dev environment and from IIS on my test server (identical text when I right-click and view source from the browser).  The IE browser in VS2010 looks as expected with a yellow border.  IE running against the test server seems to be ignoring the STYLE completely.  IE 8 and 9.0.2 both have the same behavior.  Ideas?  I don't understand why the same browser and the same markup would render on the screen differently.

```
<select name="blah" onchange="blah" id="blah" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" style="border-color:Yellow;border-style:Double;">
<option selected="selected" value="blah">blah</option>
</select>
```

Sorry I can't include the pics but I just created my new login and have no points so the site will not allow me to post pics of how these render.  Take it from me, VS2010 shows it with a yellow border (as expected) and when I run it from the test server it's got the same default bevel you normally see on the select element.

Comment: Try specifying a `border-width:` - you're possibly relying on the browser's default there.

Comment: Install Firebug and use that to debug CSS issues. (ooops...just noticed it's an IE issue. Firebug isn't a whole lot of help there, but can at least help you determine that your code is proper/valid)

Answer (score 0):

If you hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, what mode does IE say it's in?

For your IIS test server, your browser is probably setting its mode to the dreaded [**Compatibility Mode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because you are accessing your page on an intranet.  IE assumes that if you are working on an intranet you *don't* want the latest rendering styles and JavaScript enhancements because they might break your internal tools which you coded for IE 7 (you didn't, but they need to account for those that did).  See [this flow chart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx) for all of the available modes IE 8 can be put into.

If IE is in compatibility mode you will need to either:

1. Have IIS send the `X-UA-Compatible` header on every request (set the value to "edge").
2. Add a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge">` near the top of the `<head>` section of your HTML file.

Comment: F12 was new to me, and it revealed "Document Mode: IE7 standards" so I changed it to IE8 and the borders appeared.  yea!  Next I tried option 1 - could not get IIS to send it out to the browser.  Tried option 2 and it was sent to the browser, but no effect.  Finally, I tried adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> to the <head> section of the site master and that fixed the problem.  I am not sure that is the "Correct" solution so I am open to any comments regarding the downside risk of taking this route.

Comment: @Sid - adding the meta tag to the head section *is* option 2 - apologies if that wasn't clear. There aren't any downsides to it - just make sure to keep it within the first 512 bytes of your HTML file (if you put it below a bunch of CSS and JavaScript includes or as your last meta tag and the content before it adds up to more than 512 bytes it will be ignored and then you're back to IE 7 mode).

Comment: Thanks Sean, I see that I was unclear.  I first added the tag to the page I was having an issue with.  No change.  Then I added to to the "Site Master" which made it work correctly.

Comment: @Sid - glad I can help! Don't forget to click the green checkbox next to this answer if it solved your issues. :-)